# View close vote privilege

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, closing-questions

Looking at my privileges, I see one that I've qualified for and one I haven't:

- [View Close Votes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/privileges/view-close-votes), which needs 250 rep
- [Cast Close and Reopen Votes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions), which needs 500 rep

When I look at the former, it says that I should be able to view close votes—but I can't.

After reading in between the lines on that page, I see that it *actually* refers to the ability to ① view the number of/reason for close votes, ② cast close votes, and ③ cast re-open votes—but only *on questions I've created*.

However, nowhere on that page is that actually explicitly stated anywhere.

That privilege should be renamed, and the page rewritten to be more clear.

Comment: See [a similar question on the main Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68512/is-the-explanation-of-view-close-votes-misleading).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's that confusing, but worth noting that it is the same across all beta sites. It's not specific to this one or something that can likely be changed easily.